# How to run a method in the main thread after the sub-thread ends?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm new with .Net Threads. I understand that we can't work with WinForm GUI out of the main thread.
I want one of my method that update the WinForm GUI to run in the main thread right after a 2nd thread ends.
Here is a part of my code:

```
public class FormGApp : Form
{
    private Thread m_LoginThread;

    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_LoginThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.login));                   
        m_LoginThread.Start();                 
    }

    private void login()
    {
        LoginResult result = loginToServer();
        this.User = result.LoggedInUser;
    }

    private void successfullyLogin()
    {
        // Update the WinForn GUI here...
        // This method must run in the main thread!!!
    }
}
```

How can I run the method `successfullyLogin()` when `m_LoginThread` ends?

Comment: Instead of using a `Thread` why not use a `BackgroundWorker` who's "completed" event runs on the UI thread.

Comment: wich version  odf .net you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all to inspire my to use BackgroundWorker, it indeed solved this issue.
Here is my solution:

```
public partial class FormGApp : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker m_LoginBackgroundWorker;

    // ctor:
    public FormGApp()
    {
         // init thread:
         this.m_LoginBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
         this.m_LoginBackgroundWorker.DoWork += this.LoginBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
         this.m_LoginBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.LoginBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // start thread:
         this.m_LoginBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void LoginBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         this.login();
    }

    private void LoginBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         this.successfullyLogin();
    }

    private void login()
    {
         // code that take long time that executed in a separate thread... 
    }

    private void successfullyLogin()
    {
         // Gui WinForm update code here...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

1. As @ScottChamberlain said in the comment, use a `BackgroundWorker` and use its `Completed` event to update the GUI
2. Use [TPL Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the following way:

   ```
   Task.Run(() => 
     {
       //do work
     }).ContinueWith(() => 
         {
             //do continuation
         }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
   ```
3. Use `Application.Current.BeginInvoke` or `Application.Current.Invoke` from your background thread

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use async/await

```
async private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => login());
    successfullyLogin();
}
```

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0 but the point is that I don't want to wait. I want the main thread continue to work. And only when the sub thread ends the main thread well execute the method  successfullyLogin()

Comment: @GilEpshtain The point is that above code doesn't block the UI. (BTW: `I don't want to wait.` is wrong, you want to **wait** without blocking the UI)